How to do json parse in parallel
I am using Apps Script to create Looker Studio connectors.
I would like to hit an external API with the getData function and parse the response to JSON, but there are performance issues.
For example, with UrlFetchApp.fetchAll, you want to send requests to multiple URLs and turn the results into objects. The total size of each response is nearly 100MB, but you can only process each one sequentially. As a result, it takes 2~3 seconds to hit the external API and get a response, but it takes about 15 seconds to parse the JSON.
I tried CacheService to solve this problem, but the 100KB limit per key is difficult. The firebase realtime database also operates on firebase via http, so json parse is unavoidable. Therefore, I do not think this also contributes much to performance improvement.
Is there any way to execute JSON parse in parallel or cache the acquired data itself? I think there is a way to use wasm for parallel execution, but I don't want to take a difficult method if possible.

Hi TrsNium, welcome.
Maybe you can explore using the Script PropertiesService to emulate cache. PropertiesService gives you about 500k to hold the data you need. The strategy is to compile the information as small a size as possible, then stringify it to store in PropertiesService. You will need to handle the data life cycle, and that’s it.
Of course, this will work as long as the stringified object(s) you keep as cache in PropertiesService are smaller than 500k.
I use this strategy in some scripts. If it looks like a possible solution to you, I can post some example code.

Hi jpp. Thanks for the reply. My understanding is that the maximum size of a property is 500 kb per script. This limit is strict because I want to cache a maximum of almost 100MB of data.

Hi TrsNium, I see, 500k will not solve your situation as is. 100MB is a lot of data. Maybe you can reduce the size by preprocessing the information to fit the most important in 500k (or  100k) or hold the most recurrent part, or... it depends on the data and what you need to do with it.
Properties service have an additional advantage if your data does not change so often, you can expend more time to reduce the data size once a day (or a week) because you control the time to live of that "cache".
Maybe you can use a spreadsheet to hold the data between source expected changes.

Sorry, that's all i got ;-)
